# Django Model Form not displaying information stored in session

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My views.py file

```
class multi_form(View):
    model=Customer
    template_name='index.html'
    def get_initial_data(self, request):
        form=RegForm(initial={
        'first_name':request.session.get('first_name',''),
        'last_name':request.session.get('last_name',''),
        'personal_email':request.session.get('personal_email',''),
        'official_email':request.session.get('official_email',''),
        'permanent_address':request.session.get('current_address',''),
        'current_address':request.session.get('permanent_address',''),
        'pan_card_number':request.session.get('pan_card_number',''),
        'aadhar_card_number':request.session.get('aadhar_card_number',''),
        'loan_amount':request.session.get('loan_amount','')})
        return form

    def get(self, request):
        if request.session.has_key('pan_card_number'):
            form=RegForm(get_initial_data(self,request))
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'customer/index.html', context)
    
    def post(self, request):
        form=RegForm()
        if request.method=='POST':
            form=RegForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                request.session['first_name']=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                request.session['last_name']=form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                request.session['personal_email']=form.cleaned_data['personal_email']
                request.session['official_email']=form.cleaned_data['official_email']
                request.session['current_address']=form.cleaned_data['current_address']
                request.session['permanent_address']=form.cleaned_data['permanent_address']
                request.session['pan_card_number']=form.cleaned_data['pan_card_number']
                request.session['aadhar_card_number']=form.cleaned_data['aadhar_card_number']
                request.session['loan_amount']=form.cleaned_data['loan_amount']
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, "Your Response has been recorded")
                return render(request, 'customer/index.html')

            
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'customer/index.html', context)
```

What I want is the form to auto populate the fields filled earlier with those I have saved in django session variables. So, when the user has a GET request on visiting the page again he is shown the data he filled out earlier. How will I implement this thing?

My template file

```
 <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Registeration Form</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Please fill the details below</h3>
    {{form.first_name}}
    {{form.last_name}}
    {{form.personal_email}}
    {{form.official_email}}
    {{form.permanent_address}}
    {{form.current_address}}
    {{form.pan_card_number}}
    {{form.aadhar_card_number}}
    {{form.loan_amount}}
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
```

Will my template file remain the same or do I need to change it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `initial` parameter on the form for this. It will tell the form what to fill in the fields initially.

```
form = RegForm(initial={
    'first_name': request.session.get('first_name', ''),
    ...
}, ...)
```

Use it on all places where you create an instance of the form, so it might be useful to create a function `get_initial_data(request)` and then do `RegForm(initial=get_initial_data(request), ...)`.

Comment: what does this ' ' mean in 
'first_name': request.session.get('first_name', ' '),?
Should it just be empty?

Comment: It means a default value when it is not set. If it's empty it will be `None`, but I think an empty string makes more sense.

Comment: I edited my question to show the changes I made. It says get_initial_data is not a defined variable. Why so?

Comment: Ah, since you defined the function on the Class instead of in the global scope, you will have to call `self.get_initial_data(request)` instead!

Comment: Also, instead of doing `form=RegForm(initial={...}); return form` in the function, try to just return the dictionary: `return {...}`.